# connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[209.85.202.27]:2060: Connection timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, email-server

I am running in web server on EC2 instance.

My domain is registered on google

Using Postfix to send mail.

Every time i request to send mail this error pop-up:

connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[209.85.202.27]:2060: Connection timed out

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you connect to port **2060**? You should be sending through port **25** or **587**. Check your EC2 postfix settings and look for "2060" in the configs - very likely it shouldn't be there.

Also if you're *sending as* your gsuite address you should set up postfix according to these instructions: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Its Solved, It is due to EC2 blocking traffic on port 25, I have change the port